# Confusing long vs double behavior in Java

Tags: java, numbers, double, long-integer

Here is a small method that shows type-casting to double works, but plain longs do not.

```
public void test() {
    long s = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    long e = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println((double)e-(double)s);
    System.out.println(e-s);
    System.out.println(Double.SIZE);
    System.out.println(Long.SIZE);
}
```

And the output from the above method is:

```
1.8446744073709552E19
-1
64
64
```

So the question is if both double and long are 64-bit numbers in Java, then why does type-casting to double gives a better result?

**Follow-up question**:

In Java, I want to divide the whole range of long (from -2^63 to 2^63-1) into 10,000 equal ranges. How can I do the same? (some code would be really helpful).

Comment: What's confusing here? How could a long store a number bigger than the biggest number it can store (`Long.MAX_VALUE`)?

Comment: I think the point you're missing is that subtracting two `long` values always gives you a `long` answer, even if it's a mathematically incorrect one; and subtracting two `double` values always give you a `double` answer, even if it's a mathematically incorrect one.  That number `1.844....E19` is up in the territory where there are no more `long` values, but plenty of `double` values.

Comment: the   long  type-cast  to double will  also   cause  the lost  of  accuracy，the  same  as   int   type cast  to  float.

Comment: you  can  read  it  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Comment: I'm assuming you were going to calculate `(e-s)/10000` to get the length of each range. Since you can't do that, you can calculate `e/5000` instead. That would give you the same result, which is the length of each of the 10000 ranges.

Comment: I think  you should post your "follow-up question" as a separate question.  The usual rule around here is "one question per question".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Long.MAX_VALUE - Long.MIN_VALUE` is higher than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, which is why this subtraction results in numeric overflow. Therefore you don't get the correct result.

The range of numbers represented by the `double` type is wider, at the price of a lower precision (since some of the bits represent the digits of the number while the rest represent the exponent).

The fact that both `long` and `double` types use 64 bits to represent numbers doesn't mean they both support the same range of values. They don't.

The max value that can be represented by a `double` is `1.7976931348623157E308`, while the max value that can be represented by a `long` is `2^63-1`, which is much smaller (`9.223372036854776E18`).

Comment: Thanks Eran. Most helpful reply so far. Can you also help me understand how the double is able to get so high values despite being only 64-bits? Loss of precision is only in decimal part as per my understanding. Then how come it is able to extend the range of non-decimal part as well?

Comment: @user2250246 You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Thanks Eran. I added a follow-up question in the above. If you can help with that too, it would be really awesome